# Appending rows to dataframe inside for loop

Tags: r, dataframe

Essentially, I'm pulling data for every month in 2016 from an API and converting the resulting JSON into a dataframe. So, I loop over an array of months which are appended to the URL string for the API call.

Here is my code:

```
dates = c("2015-12", "2016-01", "2016-02", "2016-03", "2016-04", "2016-05", "2016-06", "2016-07", "2016-08", "2016-09", "2016-10", "2016-11")

for (month in dates) {
    url = sprintf("https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?poly=53.5803,-2.6882:53.5803,-2.6882:53.2307,-3.2389:53.2307,-3.2389&date=%s", month)
    r <- httr::GET(url)
    json <- httr::content(r, "text")

    document <- jsonlite::fromJSON(txt=json)
}
```

What I've tried to do is use `rbind` inside the loop to append upon every iteration, but the resulting dataframe is always empty.

My question is: inside this for loop, how would I iterate over each month and append each dataframe produced by the `fromJSON` function to each other into a master dataframe?

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: what package are you using for `fromJSON()`

Comment: @NathanDay `jsonlite`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not grow an object in a loop, in particular not a data.frame. That's incredibly slow. Put them into a list and `rbind` them in one step:

```
res <- lapply(dates, function(month) {
  url = sprintf("https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?poly=53.5803,-2.6882:53.5803,-2.6882:53.2307,-3.2389:53.2307,-3.2389&date=%s", month)
  r <- GET(url)
  json <- content(r, "text")

  fromJSON(txt=json)
  })

do.call(rbind, res)
```

Comment: Hi @Roland, this method also seems to produce an empty list. The `fromJSON` function is decoding the JSON inside lapply (or in my example, the loop) into a data.frame already. Could this be a problem as to why the objects aren't appending? I'm quite clueless as to why this isn't working.

Comment: The problem is not related to the loop at all. If you check outside the loop, you'll see that `json <- content(r, "text")` returns `"[]"`. In fact, if I check the URL in a web browser that's what I see.

Comment: You're right. It was the bounding lat/lon of the polygon that returned `"[]"`. Thank-you for your advice on using `lapply` by the way.

Comment: Simple rule of thumb: If you want a return value from a loop, use `lapply`, if you don't want a return value use `for`.